# Why erasing my PIC with PICKit2v2 doesn't work?

Tags: pic, pickit, icsp

Below you can see the output of **PICKit2V2** after clicking the *Erase* button:

[image]

As you can see above, all the memory addresses (I scrolled also) are equal to `3FFF`.

Now when I click on the *Read* button, this is the output:

[image]

Scrolling:

[image]

As you can see above, the erasing didn't work fine. Does this mean my PIC is dead or something?

Comment: Does *Blank Check* claim it's blank?

Comment: @Majenko Nope, It say that : **Program Memory is not blank starting at address 0x000000**

Comment: What voltage are you powering the chip with?

Comment: @Majenko I don't powered the chip. My programmer use USB port as its power supply. So I can say 5v!?

Comment: Try running the program As Adminsitrator. If that does not work, it is either your PIC or Programmer faulty/dead...

Comment: @Triak Tried, Nothing changed. Now I want to add a secondary supply.(Auxiliary for the programmer)

Answer (score 1):

A bulk erase is sensitive to the chip power supply voltage.  According to the datasheet:

> When using ICSP, the part must be supplied at 4.5V to 5.5V if a bulk erase will be executed.

It could be that your USB supply, once fed through the programmer, is dropping below 4.5V. While it's enough to program the chip, it's not enough to erase it.

You can try powering the chip separately from an external 5V power supply to see if that then allows you to erase the chip.

Comment: using a 6 volt power supply can make any problem? I have a power supply that its output is 5.85 v.

Comment: 6V is good. According to the datasheet (you should read it some time), Vdd can be anywhere between -0.3 to +7.5V.  +5.5V is the recommended maximum but it can cope with (at least for short periods) with up to 7.5V.

Comment: I know that this voltage is good for MCU. I was meant 6v couldn't make any problem with my USB port? Using another auxiliary power supply on MCU-pins is equal to Parallel 6v with USB port, is not it?

Comment: There will be a diode (or similar device) in the programmer's USB connection to stop back-powering.

Comment: There is a green LED on the programmer's board that when I connect the power supply to PIC pins, It turns off!Any comment?

Comment: What programmer hardware is it?  If you are using an official Pickit2 there will be no issues with what Majenko suggests.

Comment: Just because PICkit 2 _says_ that it's putting out 5V, doesn't mean that it is! Select menu "Tools/Calibrate VDD...", measure the actual voltage on the PIC, and type in the value. Then try erasing the chip again.